# Weird results when calculating the sum of digits of a String

Tags: java-8, java-stream

This code streams a string into an IntStream of char values and adds up the individual values:

```
private static int getSumOfDigits(String line) {
        return line.chars().sum();
    }
```

**If you input 23 you might expect to get 5 as a result, but apparently I get 101**. What is going wrong here?

Comment: It doesn't return 2+3 it does return sum of char codes of '2' and '3' which is 50 + 51. See http://www.asciitable.com/ . And note that Java string contains also non-ascii characters since it's encoding char using 2 bytes.

Comment: Damn, I thought the first 10 Asciis would be literal numbers but then I recalled the first 48 are special characters. Character.getNumericValue(char) is necessary here to convert the chars to int.

Comment: If you know they are just going to be digits '0'-'9' you can safely subtract '0' to get the numeric value.  e.g. `'7' - '0'` is 7.

Comment: True, but as with concatenating an empty string to a char, I think this kind of type conversion smells a bit.

Comment: This kind of conversion doesn’t smell—it’s the absence of a pre-test that smells. If you prepend a test of the string format, there is nothing wrong performing an operation relying on the format, e.g. `if(!line.matches("[0-9]*")) throw new IllegalArgumentException(); else return line.chars().sum() - '0'*line.length();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Martin Seeler is right. You need to convert the Characters to ints:

```
return line.chars()
           .filter(Character::isDigit)
           .map(Character::getNumericValue)
           .sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is, that it's not the numerical value you are adding, it's the ascii value for the character `2` and `3`, which is `50` and `51`.

To get the real result, you can use `java.lang.Character.getNumericValue` to convert the character into the number you're expecting.